# Google Map custom marker not working

Tags: javascript, html, maps

I am having issues with my custom markers on a Google map.
First one displays, the second one doesn't.

My JS:

```
var tout;
function myFunction() {
    tout = setTimeout(initMap, 2500);
}
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 11,
          center: {lat: 50.1821952, lng: 12.7067494}
        });
    var image = 'learn.png';
    var SCMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: 50.1760219, lng: 12.6382292},
      map: map,
      icon: image
    });
    var image2 = 'home.png';
    var HOMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: -50.1858299, lng: 12.7487256},
      map: map,
      icon: image2
    });
```

The image file is okay. What could be the issue?

Comment: Problem might be with latitude and longitude.Try changing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If images is ok, then change `position: {lat: -50.1858299, lng: 12.7487256}` to `{lat: 50.1858299, lng: 12.6382292}` and check. Icons should be nearly and you can see if icons renders or not.

Maybe it's because of "**-**".

Hope it helps!